# Source file in project from different folder in R

Tags: r

I have a function `check.R` which requires function `get.R` (I use `source("get.R")`), and both of them are in the same folder.

But in a new project and new folder, I want to source `check.R`. It doesn't load `get.R` because the working directory is the new project's working directory.

How can I source a file located in another directory?

Comment: You can `source` files using their full absolute file path or a relative file path.

Answer (score 1):

Just supply the full path of the file to `source` either as an absolute or relative path.

e.g. With this structure:

```
           |
  -------------------
  |                 |
foldA             foldB
  |                 |
fileA.R           fileB.R
```

From fileA.R you could do:

```
source("../foldB/fileB.R")
```

If needed you could use the `chdir = TRUE` parameter to temporarily change the working directory.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `setwd('[full path goes here]')` to change the working directory in `R`.